# using pytz library, convert a list of utc offsets (e.g. UTC-10:00) to named time zones (e.g. Pacific/Honolulu)

Tags: python, list, rest, python-datetime, pytz

i`m trying to translate this list of utc offsets:

```
 ['UTC-12:00','UTC-11:00','UTC-10:00','UTC-09:00','UTC-08:00','UTC-07:00','UTC-06:00','UTC-05:00','UTC-04:00','UTC+10:00','UTC+12:00']
```

into a list of named time zones using pytz library
e.g. Pacific/Honolulu

after an hour of fighting with chatgpt i was always getting an error message and conflicting results from chatgpt.
after talking with my teacher she offered this solution:

```
tz = pytz.FixedOffset(180)
now = timezone.now()
local_now = tz.normalize(now.astimezone(tz))
```

after which i was getting an error regarding `timezone` having no attribute `now`

not sure if related or not but the list of timezones are recieved through dict indexing (think that is the correct term)  from a json file recieved from the nationalize.io free rest api

```
country_timezones = list(restcountries_country_info.json()[0]['timezones'])
countries_details[country_code]['timezones'] = country_timezones
```

Comment: Multiple time zones can share the same offset at  a certain instance in time, so you cannot map UTC offsets to time zones unambiguously. Your teacher should have told you that first. Then, [pytz is deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/). Regardless of that, you can still create timezone objects from mere UTC offsets. Would that help you? What are you intending to do with the time zones?

Comment: The point of the exeracise was to interact with the nationalize.io free rest api to get a list of countries where a name originates from, and then extract data about each country (full name, continent, languages and timezones) in the original assignment the teacher told us as a hint to use the pytz library to display timezones in a prettier way so thats my goal with my question.
is there a way to narrow down my possible timezones? for example if the country is US to get throught pytz the time zone relevant to us throught the utc offsets?

Comment: after finalizing this set with pytz my plan is to advance y solution to use classes and such but first i want to complete this.
just to clarify since i missed this - extracting the data about countries is through restcountries.com rest api